# mySQL query to find first event on a series of events by type

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have an events table in mySQL which stores events that can finish with status of either `success` or `failed`.

I wish to find the first failure of the last failing events series.

for example:

```
 id  time     status
------------------
  1  10:00   success
  2  10:01   success
  3  10:03   failed
  4  10:04   failed
  5  10:05   success
  6  10:06   success
  8  10:07   failed
  9  10:07   failed
  10 10:07   failed
```

I need a query that will return `8  10:07   failed`

the first failure on the last failing events series

probably need to use a window function which I am not that good at.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's another way to do this, but I often do this with an inner query, and utilise a min group by.

```
select
    d.*
from data d
inner join (
    select 
        min(id) id, 
        time 
    from data 
    group by time
) l on d.id = l.id
```

[Here's a](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/155c60/1) SQL Fiddle of this in practice